# Buy games in Online Stores for PS4

Tags: ps4, psn

I want to buy some game for my PS4. I saw a couple of them that are in sales in some online stores, like Amazon, or CDKey Webs.

But actually I don't have PSN Plus, and I want to know if is needed to download the game (I have Internet connection and PS4 is connected to it, which I know is needed to download the game)

For example this game: https://www.g2a.com/the-last-of-us-remastered-ps4-cd-key-us.html

Comment: So your question is if you need PS+ for downloading the games?

Comment: Yes , sorry I'll edit the question if is not well formualted

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: **No** you dont need PS+ to [download games or dlc's](https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140925154205AAkWeHc). Entering keys you bought on any site is the same like buying it in the PlayStation Store. However you'll need a subscription (most of the time) if you want to use the Multiplayer features of such games.

Comment: Perfect, well.. for the moment, no multiplayer for me.. no time to play multis.. xD