# Can I re-download digital copies of games I've purchased without Playstation Plus?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

Can you delete a game purchased from the Playstation store then re-install without a subscription at a later date?

Comment: What subscription? Playstation Plus?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure I don't have Playstation plus

Comment: Will it remain in your library under purchased

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226344/buy-games-in-online-stores-for-ps4

Comment: Are you referring to games you got free copies of from past PS+ subscriptions or just games you've bought in the past?

Answer (score 8):

If you delete a digital game that you have purchased through the PSN, you can redownload it from the store as long as you are logged into the account that purchased it initially. I constantly delete and redownload games depending on what I feel like playing, as I do not have enough storage space on my PS4 to hold all of the things I have purchased digitally, so I can confirm this myself.

As a side note, PS+ is never required to access content that you have ***purchased***, however, content given for free as a bonus for being a Playstation+ member *will* expire if your subscription expires and you will lose access to it.

To see games that you own (downloaded or not), look at your library. It will have all of the software you have licenses for. See [here](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/store---transactions/store-content/how-to-download-or-stream-playstation-store-content-to-playstati0/):

> #### Where to find your PlayStation Store purchases
>
> Your most recently downloaded full games are added to the content launcher. If your purchase is not visible on the content launcher, you can find it in your  [Library]. Your Library is arranged with all content grouped together, so if you have purchased DLC, go to the main title to find it.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/1v7o27/redownloading_games/) is some confirmation of this:

> Anything you've ever purchased is tied to your PSN account, so you can redownload any time you need.
>
> There are several ways to re-download, but the easiest is to pull up your download history in the Store.

[Here](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/store---transactions/store-content/how-to-download-or-stream-playstation-store-content-to-playstati0/) are the official Sony instructions on how to download digital copies of games.

> #### How to download from the PS4 Library
>
> 1. Select your local user account and go to  [Library].
> 2. Select the game or add-on you want to download (add-ons are in a ‘folder’ with the main title).
> 3. Select ‘Download’ on the content screen.

As mentioned by Joe W, if the game has been removed from the store, you will not be able to re-download it once it has been deleted.

The only example I can think of like this is the [Silent Hills demo P.T.](http://www.polygon.com/2015/5/5/8557807/pt-silent-hills-demo-pulled) that only a select number of users still have, since the demo was removed from the store and made unavailable for redownload.

Comment: He's asking about what if his subscription to PSN elapses and he's not resubbing to PSN. will he still be able to download his games?

Comment: @Nzall his question does not indicate this at all, since he said *purchased*, and one of his comments insinuated that he does not (and did not) have PS+, but I am asking to clarify.

Comment: Should include a note that mentions it still being available in the store, while I can't remember the name of the game I do recall at least one game having been removed from the store and I got a warning about not being able to reinstall.

Comment: @JoeW, I edited my answer for this. If you happen to remember the name of the game/software that you experienced this with, feel free to add that into the answer or comment it for me to add.

Comment: It is possible for a game to not be in the store but to still be in your library. (This happened to me with "Settlers of Cataan", which is not on the PS3 store but is in my PS3 download list.)

Comment: @StevenBurnap right, I think that's what Joe W was talking about: deleting a game that is no longer downloadable from the store.

Comment: What I mean is that you can still download it, just not from the store link (which doesn't exist).  Instead, you have to find it in the download list.   (PS3 equivalent of the library)

Comment: @StevenBurnap right, but in the case of P.T., even attempting to redownload from the PS4 Library would not work (despite saying that it would in the UI)

Comment: What I remember was it was an early ps+ game for the ps4 and the message said I would not be able to redownload it again. But my memory could be bad on it also.

Comment: Yeah, P.T. is a very special case.  Also, it's a demo, not purchased content.

Comment: @StevenBurnap yeah, I don't think you can lose content you've paid for.

Answer (score -1):

- Launch the PS Store
- Go to the very bottom of the page
- There should be a button saying 'Purchased'
- Select it and pick game you want to download