# Can I play a PS4 game on 2 PS4s without moving the disc?

Tags: ps4

I have a PS4 (original version) and a new Slim PS4 at two different locations.

I would like to be able to play the games I have at either place, without having to move the games between them. Some games I have are purchased via discs, others via download from the PlayStation Store.

Is it possible to share the games between the 2 PS4s without having to physically move the discs between the 2 places?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the discs part - no.  The disc is used to validate that you own the game.  Even if you install the game off the disk, the console will expect to see the disc.  The PS4 uses the disc to basically say "Hey! You really do own this game!" If this wasn't the case, you could essentially buy one disc and share it among many people and they would all have the ability to play the game if they install it to their PS4.

For your downloaded games - yes.  You will just have to download the game onto both consoles.  As long as you are using the account you purchased the game with, it should work.  [Digital purchases are linked to your account](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/288360/163757).